# Core Plot: X axis labels curled up

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot, xcode4.5

I am adding scatter plots to my app and I want to show on the X axis labels the items contained in an array, cogsetUsed (ie, a bicycle cogset). The number of items can go from 8 to 11.

What I get is the following:

[image: screen capture]

This is the piece of code:

```
CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;

CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;

x.visibleRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(12)];
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
x.majorTickLength =4.0f;
x.tickDirection =CPTSignNegative;
CGFloat recordCount = [cogsetUsed count];
NSMutableSet *xLabels =[NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:recordCount];
NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:recordCount];
NSInteger i =0;
for (NSString *sprocket in cogsetUsed) {
    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:sprocket  textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    CGFloat location = i++;
    label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
    label.offset =x.majorTickLength;
    if (label) {
        [xLabels addObject:label];
        [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
    }
}
x.axisLabels = xLabels;
x.majorTickLocations = xLocations;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Core Plot doesn't prevent collisions between labels. There is no requirement that every tick mark be labeled. Since you're making custom axis labels anyway, don't label every tick location. It looks like you could label every third or fourth tick to get a good appearance.